A Complex Absolute Value Inequality
Following on from my previous question, is it true that, if $Rez\ge1$, then $$|1+z+\dots+z^n|>|z|^n-1 \tag{1}$$ for every natural $n$?
I wasn't able to generalize the answers given there for the case $n=3$.
Again, I used Maple to plot this inequality for some small values of $n$, with $z$ raging from $1-100i$ to $100+100i$, and even a stronger inequality seems to hold, $$|1+z+\dots+z^n|\ge|z|^n \tag{2}$$ so my guess is that even $(2)$ holds.
Am I right?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162910/42969

@MartinR WOW! How did you find that post?

With Approach0. – Compare How to search on this site?, in particular How to search with Approach0.

But, I'm not satisfied with that proof... There he says, near the end, that if $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geq 1$, then $\frac{2}{|z|^{n-1}} \leq 1$ ... Is that so???

That question is about complex numbers $z = a+ib$ with integer coordinates $a, b$, $a \ge 1$. After a first quick read of the answer I thought that the same proof works for real coordinates as well, but as you noticed, it does not. So it is not a duplicate. Still, that Q&A might lead to some ideas that solve your problem.

I see... Thanks anyway!

Fact 1. Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathrm{Re}(z) \ge 1$. Then
$|1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^n| \ge |z|^n$.
Proof of Fact 1.
The non-trivial case is $z \ne 1$. The desired inequality is written as
$$|z^{n+1} - 1|^2 \ge |z - 1|^2|z|^{2n},$$
or
$$1 - z^{n+1} - \bar{z}^{n+1} 
+ |z|^{2n} (z + \bar{z} - 1) \ge 0.$$
Let $z = r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$
where $r > 0$, $\theta \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$,
and $r\cos \theta \ge 1$. We need to prove that
$$f(r) := 1 - 2r^{n+1}\cos (n+1)\theta
+ r^{2n}(2r \cos \theta - 1) \ge 0.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 f'(r) &= -2(n+1)r^n\cos (n+1)\theta
 + 2nr^{2n-1}(2r\cos\theta - 1) + r^{2n}\cdot 2\cos\theta\\
 &\ge -2(n+1)r^n\cos (n+1)\theta
 + 2nr^{2n-1}(2 - 1) + r^{2n-1}\cdot 2\\
 &= -2(n+1)r^n\cos (n+1)\theta
 + 2(n+1)r^{2n-1}\\
 &= 2(n+1)r^n [r^{n-1} - \cos (n+1)\theta]\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we use $r\cos \theta \ge 1$ and $r \ge 1$.
Thus, it suffices to prove that $f(1/\cos\theta) \ge 0$, or
$$1 - \frac{2\cos (n+1)\theta}{\cos^{n+1}\theta}
+ \frac{1}{\cos^{2n}\theta} \ge 0.$$
WLOG, assume that $0\le \theta < \pi/2$. We split into two cases.
(1) $\theta \le \frac{\pi}{n+1}$
We have $\cos (n+1)\theta \le \cos \theta$.
We have
$$1 - \frac{2\cos (n+1)\theta}{\cos^{n+1}\theta}
+ \frac{1}{\cos^{2n}\theta} 
\ge 1 - \frac{2\cos \theta}{\cos^{n+1}\theta}
+ \frac{1}{\cos^{2n}\theta} = (1 - 1/\cos^n\theta)^2 \ge 0. $$
(2) $\theta > \frac{\pi}{n+1}$
It suffices to prove that
$$1 - \frac{2}{\cos^{n+1}\theta}
+ \frac{1}{\cos^{2n}\theta} \ge 0.$$
Let $w := \frac{1}{\cos \theta}$. It suffices to prove that, for all $w \ge (\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1})^{-1}$,
$$1 - 2w^{n+1} + w^{2n} \ge 0.$$
We can prove that $(\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1})^{-1} \ge 1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}$ for all $n\ge 3$, by using $\cos u \le 1-\frac12 u^2+\frac{1}{24}u^4$ for all $u\ge 0$. Thus, it suffices to prove that, for all $w \ge 1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}$,
$$g(w) := 1 - 2w^{n+1} + w^{2n} \ge 0.$$
We have, for all $w \ge 1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}$,
$$g'(w) = 2w^n (nw^{n-1} - n-1)
\ge 2w^n\left(n \left(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n-1} - n - 1\right) > 0$$
where we use the Bernoulli inequality to
obtain $(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2})^{n-1}
\ge 1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}\cdot (n - 1)$,
and $n [1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}\cdot (n - 1)] -n  - 1 = \frac{5n-7}{2n} > 0$.
Thus, it suffices to prove that $g(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}) \ge 0$, or
$$1 - 2 \left(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n+1}
+ \left(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{2n} \ge 0,$$
or
$$\left(\left(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n} - 1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^2 \ge \frac{28n^2+ 49}{4n^4},$$
or
$$\left(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n} - 1 - \frac{7}{2n^2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{28n^2 + 49}}{2n^2}. \tag{1}$$
(1) is true for $n = 3, 4$ by directly verifying. If $n \ge 5$, (1) is written as
$$1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}
\ge \left(1 + \frac{7}{2n^2} + \frac{\sqrt{28n^2 + 49}}{2n^2}\right)^{1/n}.$$
By Bernoulli inequality, it suffices to prove that, for all $n\ge 5$,
$$1 + \frac{7}{2n^2}
\ge 1 + \left(\frac{7}{2n^2} + \frac{\sqrt{28n^2 + 49}}{2n^2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$
which is true.
We are done.

Really nice, I need to look that better, I was trying with different strategies but it looks very difficult to prove. (+1)

What about using $w=1/z$ which reduces to the equivalent $|1+w+\ldots + w^n| \ge 1$ with $|w-1/2|=1/2$?

@user How to get $|w-1/2| = 1/2$?

@user Thanks. My solution is actually complicated, .e.g. the proof of $g\left(1 - \frac{2}{n^2}\right) \ge 0$, $1 - \frac{2}{n^2} < (\frac{n}{n+1})^{1/(n-1)}$ etc.

By inversion $w=1/z$ the line $z=1+iy$ goes to $|w-1/2|=1/2$ but also this way seems complicated.

@user That's nice relation. By the way, my case (2) is complicated. I hope there is some simpler way (such as AM-GM) for $1 - 2w^{n+1} + w^{2n}\ge 0$.

@RiverLi WOW! Took my quite a while to go through your proof... Very impressive!

This is how i solved 1
if $z=1$ you get this inequality instantly
Therefore we gonna work with $Re(z)\geq1$ and $z\neq1$
because of that $|z - 1| < |z|$ and $|z|>1$
Therefore
$|1+z+z^2+\dots+z^n|$=$\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} z^k \right|$
This is true because it represents the sum of a finite geometric series.
$\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} z^k \right| = \left| \frac{z^{n+1} - 1}{z - 1} \right| > \left| \frac{z^{n+1} - 1}{z} \right| \geq \frac{|z|^{n+1} - 1}{|z|} \geq |z|^n - 1$
so we get this inequality is true
note that I made the denominator smaller in each move

Brief and elegant...
