Inequality of geometric sequence over $\mathbb{C}$
I'm trying to prove/disprove the following inequalities (meaning each might be either correct or incorrect), $z\in \mathbb{C}$:
a. If Re$(z) \ge 1$ then: $ |1+z+z^2+...+z^n| > |z|^n-1$
b. If Re$(z) \le 0$ then: $|1+z+z^2+...+z^n|\le |z|^n +1$
Solution:
Let us define a geometric sequence, $(a_n)$, with $a_1=1$, and $q=z$.
According to the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence we get that the left side of the inequalities (a) and (b) is: $\big| \frac{z^n-1}{z-1}\big|$.
I've gotten as far as: $\big| \frac{z^n-1}{z-1} \big| \ge \big| \frac{|z|^n-1}{|z-1|}\big|$ with section (a).
This is from a list of questions in the first H.W assignment in a complex analysis course, so I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track, I'm just not sure how to continue from here, using the provided information about Re(z).
I have a feeling at least the first inequality is correct.
Any tips on how to continue?
Thank you!

These questions are almost certainly duplicate questions.

For the first inequality see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4981272/42969
